# Connecting multiple bluetooth devices causing lag

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, desktop-computer, speakers

I have my Desktop PC (with ASUS BT400 bluetooth 4.0 dongle) connected to a bluetooth speaker. The latency is unnoticeable for me. Watching movies, the audio and visuals are pretty much in-sync or close to it.

Recently I bought a bluetooth keyboard. It's connected to the same bluetooth dongle. I *feel* that when the keyboard is connected, I can start noticing latency to the speakers i.e. audio is slightly delayed when watching a movie.

Here are the questions:

1. In theory the dongle would have a bandwidth ceiling, if I reach this ceiling - will it causes latency? or simply connections start to error out?
2. Is there any way I can check the latency from and to each one of my bluetooth devices to confirm what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

this video is useful to check video-audio synchro: https://youtu.be/ucZl6vQ_8Uo﻿